# Ranking and then displaying results

Tags: excel, display, rank

I'm trying to display the name from top to bottom based on a ranking. Can't seem to find a way to pull the info I need. I looked into VLOOKUP but the order of the cells don't work for me.

Pretty simple, I have rep, number of calls, ranked based on most calls and I want to display the names in the order of ranking. I want it to look like this

Want it to look like this:
[image]

I know its a simple solution but I am stuck.

Thinking ahead, how would I deal with same results when RANK.EQ give me 2 people on 4th position for example.

Thank you!

Comment: Why doesn't an index/match work ?

Comment: You want it to look like what? The picture looks to be gone.

Comment: @teylyn When I tried to bring it back it said the link was broken :)

Answer (score 1):

In V2:W2,

```
=SMALL(T$2:T$8, ROW(1:1))
=INDEX(Q:Q, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($2:$8)/(T$2:T$8=V2), COUNTIF(V$2:V2, V2)))
```

Fill down.

[image]

Comment: Awesome, that is the result I want. Would you mind explaining a bit what that AGGREGATE does, what are the 15, 6 numbers there? what are they referencing?

Comment: See [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/aggregate-function-43b9278e-6aa7-4f17-92b6-e19993fa26df).

Comment: This worked perfectly on excel. Any idea how to make it work in google sheets?